# How can I remove rectangle in collapse navbar-collapse?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I remove the rectangle, who appear when I move the cursor in collapse navbar-collapse

[image]

```css
.navbar-nav > li > a {
  padding-top: -10px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  padding-right: 70px;
  line-height: 20px;
  list-style:solid;
  float: right; 
  display: inline;
  margin bottom: 30px;
  color: #666;
}
  

.nav > li > a:hover,
.nav > li > a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: none !important;
 }
```

```html
  <header>
  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <img src="image" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Home
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li><a href="#"> Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
```

Comment: what rectangle are you talking about? I don't see anything wrong with your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot¡Have you seen the image (home)?

Comment: yes, but could you please also give the css related to the problem. that'd make it a lot easier to solve the issue.

Comment: Have you tried adding `background-color: transparent` to `.navbar-nav > li > a`?

Comment: Thanks guys¡¡I fixed it

Comment: @bksacuesa answer your own question if its solved. This question is not going to help anyone without answer.